# ReactJS Conditional Header with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to create a conditional component called HeaderControl that can generate a type of Header for the aplication if the user is Logged or not.

This is my Header.jsx :

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { isAuthenticated } from '../Login/reducers';
import ucaLogo from '../../assets/logo.gif';
import '../../styles/base.scss';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated(state),
});

function HeaderNoLogin() {
  return <div className="header-div col-md-12">
      <img className="img-login-header" src={ucaLogo} alt="logo" />
      <div className="title-head-div">
        <p className="title-head">Not logged</p>
        <p className="title-head"> Not logged</p>
      </div>
    </div>;
}

function HeaderLogged() {
  return <div className="header-div col-md-12">
      <img className="img-login-header" src={ucaLogo} alt="" />
      <div className="title-head-div">
        <p className="title-head">Logged</p>
        <p className="title-head"> Logged</p>
      </div>
    </div>;
}

class HeaderControl extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const isLoggedIn = (props) => {
      if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    };

    let button = null;
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      button = <HeaderLogged />;
    } else {
      button = <HeaderNoLogin />;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {button}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HeaderControl);
```

My entry point (app.jsx) in have a Provider with the store like this:

```
const history = createHistory();
const store = configureStore(history);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app'),
);
```

My questions are:

1. Where and how can I check if the user is authenticate using the redux store?
2. Where and how should I import the Header ? I think that I should import it in the app.jsx but I do not know where exactly.

Sorry if these are dumbs questions but this is the first time that I am using Reactjs with Redux.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could change title, if possible and put something like async validation in redux ?

Answer (score -1):

If your a newbie docs has good example in react-router **v4** https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy. 
index.js:

```
export const store = createStore(
  app,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
); //mandatory to use async in redux

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And in app.js:

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <HeaderControl /> // header will be always visible
    <MuiThemeProvider>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  </div>
);
export default App;
```

Handle async logic with redux is not intuitive you shouldn't start by that if your new to redux.

reducers.js:

```
 import {LOGGED_IN, LOGGED_OUT} from '../actions/User'
const initialState = {
  logged: false
}
// reducer
function User (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGGED_IN:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {logged: true}, action.payload)
    case LOGGED_OUT:
      return initialState
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default User
```

You neet to setup a middlewear to handle async request in redux. It is the more simple approach. there is others options like redux saga and redux-observable. In this  example i use redux-thunk.

I advise you to check redux docs on middlweare
https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html
and/or this course on udemy https://www.udemy.com/react-redux-tutorial/

```
export const checkLogin = payload => { 
  return dispatch =>
    xhr
      .post(/login , payload) // payload is json name and password
      .then(res => dispatch(LOGGED_IN))) // response is positive
      .cath(err => console.log(err)) 
}
```

And your checkLogin action should be using in login.js form

login.js

```
import checkLogin from action.js

class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form submit={checkLogin}>
        {" "}
        // this is pseudo code but i hope it's clear , you take data from your
        form and you you call cheklogin.
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

So the logic is pretty simple:

In login you call the action checkLogin

A request will start to you server with login+pass

When the request end login reducer is call.

Reducer update state.

Header is refresh.

Comment: thanks for the reply ! How could I check if the user is logged using the state of the store in the HeaderControl class ?

Comment: If you never want to change the header for specific pages, this works well. Since the HeaderControl is inside the <Provider> you can use the redux connect HOC to grab any state you want such as your isAuthenticated flag (assuming you already store that in a reducer)